# Making a c file for a git repository

Tags: c++, arrays, git, pointers, ubuntu

I'm extremely new to Ubuntu and PuTTY and putting a C++ file into it, but I'm having a problem with my C++ file. What I need the program to do is take a string entered from the Ubuntu side, put into the C++ program, and have it count how many strings are entered in and it sends back like so:

```
./myfile Supplying arguments now
Argument #0: ./myfile
Argument #1: Supplying
Argument #2: arguments
Argument #3: now
Number of arguments printed: 4
```

So, when I run my program down below, the program goes on forever and I can't step through it. What is causing it and why and/or what can I do to fix the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int count = 0;
    while (*argv[argc] != NULL)
    {
        count++;
    }
    cout << count << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `argc` is never changing, so you're always looming at the same member of `argv`. Pay close attention to the code your write.

Comment: Also, use something like getc instead of calling pause via system.

Comment: I don't see how "GIT" plays into this. Ubuntu and PuTTY are also not relevant to this question. Apart from that: Did you want do use *argv[ count ]? Did you want to use while( count < argc )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is an infinite loop because your `while` loop always checks the same condition. That's because `argc` never changes in your code.

What you meant to write is `while (*argv[count] != NULL)`. However, what you meant isn't correct either.

1. C doesn't check array boundaries. When you read past an array boundary, you will not necessarily encounter a 0 value. You will read random garbage data which is in memory at that place.
2. You don't need to count the number of arguments yourself, because [you already have it in the variable `argc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024197/what-does-int-argc-char-argv-mean).

So a better solution to iterate all the command line arguments would be a `for` loop which increments `count` from `0` to `argc`.

Comment: Perfect, I can see where I went wrong, I couldn't step through the program which really made this a headache. Thanks a million!

Comment: I'm fairly certain that `argv[]` itself is NULL-terminated, as well - i.e. `argv[argc] == NULL`. Not sure if that's a C standard thing, or Sus, POSIX, or something else, though, and I don't have the various documents handy to dig it out. Maybe it's not universally true...